# why there are so many negative values in the kernel filter?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel

If a majority of values in a kernel are negative, after ReLU, the results would be 0s. in that case this type of kernel are useless?  Is there anything wrong with these kinds of kernels? how do we guarantee to have valid and effective kernels?

for example, these kinds of kernels

```
  [ 0.0000, -0.0925, -0.0925],
  [-0.0925, -0.0925,  0.0000],
   [ 0.0000, -0.0925, -0.0925],

   [ 0.0000, -0.0687,  0.0000],
   [-0.0687, -0.0687,  0.0000],
   [ 0.0000, -0.0687,  0.0000],
```

Comment: There is usually a bias `b` added after multiplication by the kernel `A`, i.e., `ReLU(Ax+b)`. The negative value might be necessary to inverse the vector's direction. After the bias, values can be positive, which would make these values useful. Also, if the vector `x` contains negative values, then it can be normal. However, we cannot ensure that it is valid if we don't know anything about the actual problem. All we can say is that it *might* be normal/necessary.

Comment: You are mistaken, ReLU is applied to the pre-activations (output of convolution), not to the kernel values. So that some kernel values are negative means exactly nothing.